# How can I write out decoded HTML using HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, decode, innertext

I am having partial success in my attempt to write HTML to a DOCX file using HTMLAgilityPack and the DOCX library. However, the text I'm inserting into the .docx file contains encoded html such as:

```
La ciudad de Los &Aacute;ngeles (California) ha sincronizado su&nbsp;red completa de sem&aacute;foros &mdash;casi&nbsp;4.500&mdash;, que cubre una zona de 1.215&nbsp;kil&oacute;metros cuadrados (469&nbsp;millas cuadradas). Seg&uacute;n el diario
```

What I want it to be is more like this:

```
La ciudad de Los Angeles (California) ha sincronizado su red completa de semaforos - casi 4.500 -, que cubre una zona de 1.215 kilometros cuadrados (469 millas
cuadradas). Segun el diario
```

To show some context, this is the code I'm using:

```
private void ParseHTMLAndConvertBackToDOCX()
{
    List<string> sourceText = new List<string>();
    List<string> targetText = new List<string>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocSource = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocTarget = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    // There are various options, set as needed
    htmlDocSource.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    htmlDocTarget.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

    htmlDocSource.Load(sourceHTMLFilename);
    htmlDocTarget.Load(targetHTMLFilename);

    // Popul8 generic list of string with source text lines
    if (htmlDocSource.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> pNodes = htmlDocSource.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");

        foreach (HtmlNode sText in pNodes)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sText.InnerText))
            {
                sourceText.Add(sText.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
```

. . .

The most pertinent line is no doubt:

```
sourceText.Add(sText.InnerText);
```

Should it be something other than InnerText?

Is it possible to to something like:

```
sourceText.Add(sText.InnerText.Decode());
```

?

Intellisense is not working with this, even though the project compiles and runs; trying to see what other options there are besides InnerText for HTMLNode is thus fruitless; I know there's OuterText, InnerHTML, and OuterHMTL, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
sourceText.Add(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString));
```

[Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks; just had to add a references to System.Web

Answer (score 21):

You can use `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(sText.InnerText)` from HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: I prefer this answer because no need of other code than HtmlAgilityPack.